# Max OS X: How to remove an app from Notifications completely

Tags: macos, mac, notifications

Just noticed "B&H Photo" is listed in my Mac's Notifications and is sending notifications regularly. I have turned it off by clicking "None" in the Notifications. But just wondering how to remove it from the list completely? In fact, have no idea how it is added to the list in the first place, because I am pretty sure there is no such an app that I installed.

Comment: These feature was included in the Mavericks update (http://www.imore.com/how-get-notifications-your-favorite-websites-notification-center-and-os-x-mavericks).  Not sure how to remove it from the list, but you should be able to find the text "B&H Photo" in a Notifications-related file in your Library, and remove from there (and then logout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this issue too. I didn't even know how I got notifications from them in the first place. I didn't have any B&H app, so I figured it must have come from Safari. I know I'm getting lots of requests from websites nowadays in my browser (Safari, Chrome, etc) to allow or block notifications. This seems like a bizarre trend to me, especially if the websites act outside of a web browser. Isn't that what apps are for?

But anyway, it was indeed Safari. In the Safari menu, go to Preferences, then on the Notifications tab you can see what websites asked permission to show alerts, and whether or not they are allowed. I guess they are added there whether or not you allowed them. You can remove them there. Then they also do not show in the System Preferences list (the other place you saw them). A similar thing may work with other web browsers, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of Safari notifications, in Safari/preferences/notifications:

1. Remove all registered websites (be their permission allow or deny)
   and
2. Clear the checkbox that allows websites to ask permission to
   send push notification.